# plainToInstance cannot convert complex sub-properties

Tags: typescript, class-transformer

I want to convert an Entity into a DTO object. Entities contain extra properties compared to the corresponding DTO type, which I don't want exposed.

The difficulty is that both objects contains properties that are also entities and DTOs.

It seems that `plainToInstance` struggles with sub-properties conversion.

Here is the used code to convert:

`plainToInstance(DtoA, entityObjectA, { excludeExtraneousValues: true, exposeUnsetFields: false, enableImplicitConversion: true })`

`excludeExtraneousValues` set to true to avoid exposing information.
`exposeUnsetFields` set to false to avoid polluting the DTO object.
`enableImplicitConversion` set to true to try to convert sub-entities into sub-DTO objects.

It seems that the implicit conversion does not do what I expect.

Example of the issue:

```
export class DtoA {
    public dtos: DtoB[];
}

export class DtoB {
    public dtos: DtoC[];
}

export class DtoC {
    // some properties
}
```

On entity side, properties are named the same, but of course, properties are entities, not DTOs.

When using `plainToInstance`, like above, on `EntityA`, I get:

```
{
    dtos: [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

Where sub-entities are not converted to DTO objects.

If I pass `JSON.stringify(entityObjectA)` to plainToInstance instead of `entityObjectA`, I get a a string, where all quotes are escaped, instead of an object DtoA:

```
"{\"dtos\":[{\"dtos\": ...}]}"
```

More information:

- These entities & DTO objects are declared in an external typescript library
- All DTO objects' properties have the `@expose()` decorator
- class-transformer version ^0.5.1 in both the project running `plainToInstance` and in the library

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. To use `plainToClass` or `plainToInstance` with the option `excludeExtraneousValues`, you need to set:

- `@Expose()` on all properties to set, and on the class itself, in the out class (dto classes in my question)
- `enableImplicitConversion` to true
- `@Type(() => ObjectType)` for arrays, in the example, an array containing `ObjectType` objects, ex: `public arrayOfObjects: ObjectType[];`